# Sharing Emoji to Twitter feed with Appcelerator

Tags: twitter, appcelerator, emoji

I have been using this method (https://github.com/ebryn/twitter-titanium) of authenticating with Twitter for a while now. I am currently using Ti Studio 4.2.0.201508141038, Ti SDK 3.5.1. I know this is a little old but I am on this version for support reasons.

I am trying to allow the sharing of text entered in a TextArea to twitter including emojis. For some reason sharing to Facebook works like a charm but twitter I receive "����". Please note that I have only tested iOS to date. Android will follow.

Is there some encoding method that I should be using that will get me through this?

The code I am using to post is simply as follows:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter').Twitter;

var client = Twitter({
  consumerKey: consumerKey,
  consumerSecret: consumerSecret,
  accessTokenKey: accessTokenKey, 
  accessTokenSecret: accessTokenSecret
});

client.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
  if (e.success) {
    Ti.App.Properties.setString('twitterAccessTokenKey', e.accessTokenKey);
    Ti.App.Properties.setString('twitterAccessTokenSecret', e.accessTokenSecret);

    var tweet = textArea.value.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');

    client.request("1.1/statuses/update.json", {status: tweet, trim_user:'t'}, 'POST', function(e) {
      if (e.success) {
        console.log('success');
      } else  {
        console.log('Twitter Post failed.\nDetail is:'+JSON.stringify(e.data));
      }
    });
  } else {
    Ti.API.debug(JSON.stringify(e));
  }
});

client.authorize();
```

Funnily, I found that if I make tweet equal to:

```
var tweet = textArea.value.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '') + '\ue415';
```

I do get a smiley in my tweet but only on my device not on twitter.com. But if I type that code directly into my TextArea it gets tweeted verbatum.

I have also tried using encode(tweet) and urlEncode(tweet) but they really don't work.

Is there a way I can get emojis tranlated into text that will then post correctly on twitter?

Comment: For Facebook, what do you use to share the text? Perhaps that gives us a lead on if this is a client (app) side bug or not.

Comment: Hi Fokke.  I'm using a module written by mokesmokes (https://github.com/mokesmokes/titanium-ios-facebook; https://github.com/mokesmokes/titanium-android-facebook)  I am sharing the same text directly from the TextArea.  I'm using this since I needed to use the updated SDK version prior to moving to Appc.  Once I move beyond my current support requirements I'll upgrade everything to the latest and likely swap back to the Appc Facebook module.

Comment: On thinking about it, the Facebook module I'm using (and the Appc FB mod also) uses the Facebook SDK in the background.  The twitter library I'm using accesses twitter via their restful API. Not sure that this should cause a difference though.

Comment: Well, that does make it two very different scenarios. Looking at https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-do-i-get-emojis-and-other-entities-entered-and-posted-to-twitter-via-the-api-to-appear-as-they-should/12183 it is probably an encoding issue. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update also says you (might) need to url encode (`encodeURIComponent`) the status. You could hack the twitter commonJS and replace the base URL with an http://requestb.in to view the exact request as it is send out.

Comment: If I take a console of what is about to be sent to the API as I had it, the text "Twitter test <smiley>" looked like "Twitter%20test%20%F0%9F%98%80".  And it ended up showing diamonds in Twitter.  After using encodeURICompoent(tweet), I get "Twitter%20test%20%F0%9F%98%80" and it shows exactly that in twitter.  So using the encode it looks to be moving backwards .... I'll now try to get the headers being sent.

Comment: It looks like the jsOAuth-1.3.1.js library does the url encoding for me.  Here is a breakdown of the info sent -> Method : POST - URL:https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json - HEADERS: Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest, + the Auth header.  Query sent is as before.

Comment: Output from requestb.in  follows

Comment: FORM/POST PARAMETERS

status: Twitter test 

trim_user: t

Comment: HEADERS
Total-Route-Time: 0
User-Agent: Appcelerator Titanium/3.5.1 (iPhone Simulator/8.3; iPhone OS; en_US;)
X-Titanium-Id: <Ti-ID>
Host: requestb.in
X-Request-Id: <id>
Via: 1.1 vegur
Connect-Time: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="oob", oauth_consumer_key="<key>", oauth_nonce="<aa>", oauth_signature="<sig>", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="<time>", oauth_token="<token>", oauth_version="1.0"
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 54

Comment: It might well be that https://github.com/ebryn/twitter-titanium/blob/master/Resources/jsOAuth-1.3.1.js messes with the encoding. For iOS you could also try https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework#socialtwitterrequestobject-options--object-requestparameter which uses the Twitter APIs as part of iOS.

Comment: Thanks for all of your feedback Fokke.  This has been frustrating to look into and your help means a lot.  I will be taking some time to look into your last suggestions in detail but I will update this thread for future reference on what I find. Thought that I'd add that Android works perfectly.  Emjois typed in are shared successfully (although through a wierd sometimes arbitrary Twitter filter).  So the method seems to work - there is just a difference when it comes to iOS that I need to find.

Comment: Using [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/) I found a difference between the info sent from Android and iOS.  iOS had the following 3 additional items in the header.   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate; Accept: "*/*"; Accept-Language: en-us.  I'll try to find where these are added and stop them for iOS and see if that helps.

Comment: Above is meant to be "Accept: \*/\*"

Comment: @Fokke I've looked into the libraries and these 3 header items are not added in the code.  There are also other headers that are not added (e.g. User-Agent).  The library uses `XHR = global.Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();`  So my guess is that these other headers are added by that object.  Do you know of a way I can remove one or more of these headers to test my theory?

Comment: Further testing with multiple emojis shows that Android has the same problem.  Both iOS and Android seems to work if using the embarrased emoji - fitting really. Back to the drawing board .....

Comment: So this raw data works : "status=%E2%98%BA%EF%B8%8F%20iOS%20test&trim_user=t" ........ but this raw data doesn't .... "status=%ED%A0%BD%ED%B8%83%20iOS%20test&trim_user=t"

Comment: O M G.  My apologies for not reading some of your ealier comments thoroughly @FokkeZandbergen.  Simply replacing the entire workings of the OAuth.urlEncode function in the jsOAuth-1.3.1.js CommonJS with `return encodeURIComponent(string);` works nicely!